# addMessageHandler NullPointerException with Lambda

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, java-8, bugzilla

**Tomcat 8.0.21**

This works:

```
session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String string) {
                try {
                    session.getBasicRemote().sendText(string);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(WebSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
```

This doesn't:

```
session.addMessageHandler((MessageHandler.Whole<String>) (String string) -> {
            try {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(string);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
```

Can I assume that this is a tomcat bug?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.Util.getGenericType(Util.java:192)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.Util.getGenericType(Util.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.Util.getGenericType(Util.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.Util.getMessageType(Util.java:171)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.addMessageHandler(WsSession.java:198)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:696)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: When you say "this doesn't", in what way doesn't it work? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, perfect timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which version of Tomcat you are using, but it could already be fixed: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=57788

Also, the method you are calling uses raw types and does not work in all cases. From [Tomcat Javadoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/websocketapi/javax/websocket/Session.html#addMessageHandler(javax.websocket.MessageHandler)) for `addMessageHandler(MessageHandler)`:

> The message type will be derived at runtime from the provided `MessageHandler` instance. It is not always possible to do this so it is better to use `addMessageHandler(Class, javax.websocket.MessageHandler.Partial)` or `addMessageHandler(Class, javax.websocket.MessageHandler.Whole)`.

Try this instead:

```java
session.addMessageHandler(String.class, (String string) -> { ... } )
```

Comment: Please refresh your page

Comment: That bugfix will be in the next version of Tomcat (8.0.22) but it will probably just change the error message -does it work if you pass `String.class`?

Comment: It seems that swapping out `(MessageHandler.Whole<String>)` for `String.class` did indeed resolve the issue. I will test with **8.0.22**.

Comment: I assume 8.0.22 will fail with another error unless you pass `String.class`. Use of the method without explicit class parameter is discouraged.